# How to develop an action methods that convert model objects into Excel sheet (.xls)and text file (.csv)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, entity-framework-4

I have the following view inside my asp.net mvc web application:, it simply display the model data inside a table and there are three check boxes at the table Colum heads to select which columns should be extracted to excel (.xls) or text (.csv) files.
The view is:-

```
@model MvcApplication4.Models.SelectedCustomers

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CustomerDetials";
}
<h3>Select Customers Detials</h3>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            NAME @Html.CheckBox("Name",true)
        </th>
        <th>
            Description @Html.CheckBox("Description",true)
        </th>
        <th>
            Address @Html.CheckBox("Address",true)
        </th>
    </tr>
@foreach (var item in Model.Info) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.address)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Back","customer","Home") |
<a href="">extract to excel</a> |
<a href="">extract to text file</a>
</p>
```

But can anyone provide some help on how i can accomplish the following:-

1. Develop a action methods that will return & open an excel sheet containing the SelectedCustomer model objects when the user click on the " extract to excel " link.
2. Develop a action methods that will return & open a .csv file containing the SelectedCustomer model objects when the user click on the " extract to text file " link.
3. How can i only extract the columns that have their check box "selected".

Thanks & Best Regards

**:::UPDATED:::**

I have updated my view to the following:-

```
@model MvcApplication4.Models.SelectedCustomers

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CustomerDetials";
}

<h3>Select Customers Detials</h3>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Export", null))
{

<table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                NAME @Html.CheckBox("IncludeName",true)
            </th>
            <th>
                Description @Html.CheckBox("IncludeDescription",true)
            </th>
            <th>
                Address @Html.CheckBox("IncludeAddress",true)
            </th>
        </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.Info) {
    <tr>

       <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.description)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.address)
            </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Back","customer","Home") |
        <button type="submit" name="format" value="xls">extract to excel</button> |
        <button type="submit" name="format" value="csv">extract to text file</button>
    </p>}
```

Then  have added the folloiwng action metthods:-

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Export(ExportViewModel exportOptions,IEnumerable<Account> sc)
        {
          //  var accounts = GetAccounts();
            if (exportOptions.Format == "csv")
            {
                return sc.AsCsvResult(exportOptions);
            }
            else if (exportOptions.Format == "xls")
            {
                return sc.AsXlsResult(exportOptions);
            }

            throw new NotSupportedException(
                string.Format("Unsupported format: {0}", exportOptions.Format)
            );
        }
```

And the following Model class:-

```
public abstract class ExportAccountsResult : ActionResult
{
    protected ExportAccountsResult(IEnumerable<Account> accounts, ExportViewModel exportOptions)
    {

        this.Accounts = accounts;
        this.ExportOptions = exportOptions;
    }

    protected IEnumerable<Account> Accounts { get; private set; }
    protected ExportViewModel ExportOptions { get; private set; }

    protected abstract string ContentType { get; }
    protected abstract string Filename { get; }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.ContentType = ContentType;
        var cd = new ContentDisposition
        {
            FileName = this.Filename,
            Inline = false
        };
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());

        // TODO: Use a real CSV parser here such as https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/wiki/Basics
        // and never roll your own parser as shown in this oversimplified
        // example. Here's why: http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(response.OutputStream))
        {
            foreach (var account in this.Accounts)
            {
               var values = new List<object>();
            if (this.ExportOptions.IncludeName)
            {
                values.Add(account.Name);
            }
            if (this.ExportOptions.IncludeDescription)
            {
                values.Add(account.Description);
            }
            if (this.ExportOptions.IncludeAddress)
            {
                values.Add(account.Address);
            }
            writer.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", values));
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

and the following model class:-

```
namespace MvcApplication4.Models
{
    public class ExportViewModel
    {
        public string Format { get; set; }
        public bool IncludeName { get; set; }
        public bool IncludeDescription { get; set; }
        public bool IncludeAddress { get; set; }

    }
}
```

And the folloiwng model class:-

```
namespace MvcApplication4.Models
{
    public class CsvResult : ExportAccountsResult
    {
        public CsvResult(IEnumerable<Account> accounts, ExportViewModel exportOptions)
            : base(accounts, exportOptions)
        {
        }

        protected override string ContentType
        {
            get { return "text/csv"; }
        }

        protected override string Filename
        {
            get { return "accounts.csv"; }
        }
    }

}
```

and the folloiwng model class:-

```
namespace MvcApplication4.Models
{
    public class XlsResult : ExportAccountsResult
    {
        public XlsResult(IEnumerable<Account> accounts, ExportViewModel exportOptions)
            : base(accounts, exportOptions)
        {
        }

        protected override string ContentType
        {
            get { return "application/vnd.ms-excel"; }
        }

        protected override string Filename
        {
            get { return "accounts.csv"; }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the folloiwng model class:-

```
namespace MvcApplication4.Models
{
    public class SelectedCustomers
    {
        public IEnumerable<Account> Info { get; set; }
    }
    public static class ActionResultextensions
    {
        public static ActionResult AsCsvResult(this IEnumerable<Account> accounts, ExportViewModel exportOptions)
        {
            return new CsvResult(accounts, exportOptions);
        }

        public static ActionResult AsXlsResult(this IEnumerable<Account> accounts, ExportViewModel exportOptions)
        {
            return new XlsResult(accounts, exportOptions);
        }
    }
}
```

But when i run the application i got the following exception :-

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=MvcApplication4
  StackTrace:
       at MvcApplication4.Models.ExportAccountsResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) in c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MvcApplication4\MvcApplication4\Models\ExportAccountResult.cs:line 43
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
  InnerException:
```

on this code inside the ExportAccountResult.cs:-

```
foreach (var account in this.Accounts)
```

So what might be getting wrong?
BR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the records into a form and make the 2 links submit buttons. Let's take an example. We will use CSV for both the text file and Excel file format because Excel understands CSV. If you need to apply some special formatting for the Excel export you will could use a third party library such as [OpenXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx).

Let's start by defining our view models:

```
public class SelectedCustomers
{
    public IEnumerable<Account> Info { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public class ExportViewModel
{
    public string Format { get; set; }
    public bool IncludeName { get; set; }
    public bool IncludeDescription { get; set; }
    public bool IncludeAddress { get; set; }
}
```

then we could have a controller with 2 actions - one that renders the records on the view and one that exports them:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new SelectedCustomers
        {
            Info = GetAccounts()
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Export(ExportViewModel exportOptions)
    {
        var accounts = GetAccounts();
        if (exportOptions.Format == "csv")
        {
            return accounts.AsCsvResult(exportOptions);
        }
        else if (exportOptions.Format == "xls")
        {
            return accounts.AsXlsResult(exportOptions);
        }

        throw new NotSupportedException(
            string.Format("Unsupported format: {0}", exportOptions.Format)    
        );
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Account> GetAccounts()
    {
        // TODO: those records will probably come from a database or something
        // I have hardcoded them here to make my answer more clear
        // and not dependent on some data stores
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(x => new Account
        {
            Name = "name " + x,
            Description = "description " + x,
            Address = "address " + x
        });
    }
}
```

then we define the corresponding view:

```
@model SelectedCustomers

<h3>Select Customers Detials</h3>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Export", null))
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                NAME @Html.CheckBox("IncludeName", true)
            </th>
            <th>
                Description @Html.CheckBox("IncludeDescription", true)
            </th>
            <th>
                Address @Html.CheckBox("IncludeAddress", true)
            </th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Info) {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>

    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back","customer","Home") |
        <button type="submit" name="format" value="xls">extract to excel</button> |
        <button type="submit" name="format" value="csv">extract to text file</button>
    </p>
}
```

Next we implement the custom extension methods used in the controller that return the 2 custom action results:

```
public static class ActionResultextensions
{
    public static ActionResult AsCsvResult(this IEnumerable<Account> accounts, ExportViewModel exportOptions)
    {
        return new CsvResult(accounts, exportOptions);
    }

    public static ActionResult AsXlsResult(this IEnumerable<Account> accounts, ExportViewModel exportOptions)
    {
        return new XlsResult(accounts, exportOptions);
    }
}
```

And the last part of course is to define the `CsvResult` and `XlsResult` custom action results. Since we will be using CSV in both cases we could have a base class:

```
public abstract class ExportAccountsResult : ActionResult
{
    protected ExportAccountsResult(IEnumerable<Account> accounts, ExportViewModel exportOptions)
    {
        this.Accounts = accounts;
        this.ExportOptions = exportOptions;
    }

    protected IEnumerable<Account> Accounts { get; private set; }
    protected ExportViewModel ExportOptions { get; private set; }

    protected abstract string ContentType { get; }
    protected abstract string Filename { get; }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.ContentType = ContentType;
        var cd = new ContentDisposition
        {
            FileName = this.Filename,
            Inline = false
        };
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());

        // TODO: Use a real CSV parser here such as https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/wiki/Basics
        // and never roll your own parser as shown in this oversimplified
        // example. Here's why: http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(response.OutputStream))
        {
            foreach (var account in this.Accounts)
            {
                var values = new List<object>();
                if (this.ExportOptions.IncludeName)
                {
                    values.Add(account.Name);
                }
                if (this.ExportOptions.IncludeDescription)
                {
                    values.Add(account.Description);
                }
                if (this.ExportOptions.IncludeAddress)
                {
                    values.Add(account.Address);
                }
                writer.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", values));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then we could have the 2 implementations:

```
public class CsvResult : ExportAccountsResult
{
    public CsvResult(IEnumerable<Account> accounts, ExportViewModel exportOptions)
        : base(accounts, exportOptions)
    {
    }

    protected override string ContentType
    {
        get { return "text/csv"; }
    }

    protected override string Filename
    {
        get { return "accounts.csv"; }
    }
}

public class XlsResult : ExportAccountsResult
{
    public XlsResult(IEnumerable<Account> accounts, ExportViewModel exportOptions)
        : base(accounts, exportOptions)
    {
    }

    protected override string ContentType
    {
        get { return "application/vnd.ms-excel"; }
    }

    protected override string Filename
    {
        get { return "accounts.csv"; }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tired the code but it gave some erros, but i think on the  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Export(ExportViewModel exportOptions)
    {
i should be passing the SelectedCustomer object which are on the view instead of getting the Account uisng the GetAccounts method. CAN YOU ADVICE PLEASE..

Comment: No, you should not be passing `SelectedCustomer` to the `Export` action. You should be passing the `ExportViewModel` as shown in my answer. As far as the error you got I cannot advice you anything without you first telling what error you got, right? I cannot read your mind. I have tested the code on my PC and it worked fine. If it doesn't work on your this probably means that you did something wrong.

Comment: thanks , i have updated my original post with the updated code and the error i am getting. thnaks

Comment: The problem is that you have commented the `var accounts = GetAccounts();` line from my original code and you have added an `IEnumerable<Account>` parameter to the controller action. Except that inside the form there are no other input fields except the checkboxes => you cannot possibly expect that this parameter will be passed to your controller action to something else than null. That;s why you are getting a NullReferenceException. You will have to query your data store (the same way you did in the GET action) in order to retrieve the account information when exporting. Please read my answer

Comment: but that data in the view -the html table that contain the check boxes- are not stored in the database they are stored in the memory in a viewmidel object, so i need to pass them from the view to the export action method. otherwise i will not be able to reference them ..

Comment: You have fetched them in the GET action from somewhere, right? You should fetch them from the same location in your export action. If the data is in-memory then it's even easier, all you have to do is to retrieve them.

Comment: you are right ,, now it worked fine i have added "@Html.Hidden(String.Format("Info[{0}].ORG_ID", c), item.ORG_ID)" to the view and now the SelectedCustomer are being passed to the action method.But one last thing is missing is that the excel sheet does not have header for the columns. Br

Comment: You could easily add the header. Just modify the ExecuteResult method in my example and add an additional line in the generated CSV containing the column names. Once again you will need to check if a column has been selected using the corresponding boolean values in the view model.

Comment: thanks again i added the following and the header is being displayed:- var valuesheader = new List<object>();
                if (this.ExportOptions.IncludeOrgName)
                {
                    valuesheader.Add("Name");
                }
                if (this.ExportOptions.IncludeLoginURI)
                {
                    valuesheader.Add("Login URI");
                }
                if (this.ExportOptions.IncludeEmail)
                {
                    valuesheader.Add("SUPPORT EMAIL");
                }
                writer.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", valuesheader));

Comment: last thing is that both the "extract to excel" & "extract to text" buttons will generate the same .csv files and  will have the same effect . So is there a way to automatically open the "export to excel" file using MS excel while to open the "export to text" uisng a wordpad or notepad ?

Comment: No, that's not possible to be controlled from the web application. It will all depend on which program is configured to open which file type on the client computer. There's not much that could be done from the server. All you could do is send the proper Content-Type header and leave the client handle it.